# how to upload sql server 2008 database to the production server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, production-environment, uploading

hey guys,
i am creating a website for a client, my website is almost complete, now i want to upload the database to the clients production server, but i dont have any hint about how to upload the database to the production server. can anyone please help me with the steps how to upload the sql server 2008 database to the production server, keeping in mind, the production is not the dedicated server, i think i have to run my database script, on the server, but i dont know how to run, will i get the option for the same on the production server, or need to dig for the same on the sql server...

Please help me for this as soon as possible..
Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of few methods.

For example,
If you have version controlled database objects in Visual Studio then you can just deploy it to server by specifying production database connection. This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833271.aspx) can help you in that case.

Or,
You can take backup of your current development database and restore it to production server. If you have never worked with backup and restore, read on these MSDN links, for [Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), for [Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx). Of course, in normal situation Backup/Restore is not this straight forward but since your system is new and not in use, this should be easy task.

Or,
Script out database objects from current development server and run those scripts to production server (say by using Sql Server Management Studio). Generating scripts is easy but I don't think anyone can explain it step-by-step in few lines. But you can read this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) for detailed information.